# Open javascript window into AlertDialog

Tags: android, webview, window.open, webchromeclient

In my app I've a webview displayed correctly. 
In the site there is a button that when clicked make a window.open() displaying some information.
I've added a webchromeclient with the override of onCreateWindow method and add setSupportMultipleWindows(true) to the webview.
It is called but I dont't how to display the content of the page into a dialog or how to show this page in a new window of the webview.
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

In your `onCreateWindow()` implementation, you need something like this:

```
WebView.WebViewTransport transport = (WebView.WebViewTransport) resultMsg.obj;

// Create a new WebView here and display it to the user
newWebView = ...

transport.setWebView(newWebView);
resultMsg.sendToTarget();

return true;
```